# Intersect between two mysql table row

Tags: mysql, database, intersection

I want find intersection between two row. For example A table has ADSL column and B table has ADSL column too. You can see  from images there is so much same columns. Tables have datas. I wanna intersect columns between these datas. I hope you can understand, sorry for my english.

https://i.hizliresim.com/7qRvyl.png

https://i.hizliresim.com/r3P9JP.png

By the way, this is not my homework.

Comment: Pls provide the expected output and the query you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want a standard join:

```
SELECT * FROM A, B WHERE A.adsl = B.adsl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make one SELECT query for one table, and make one SELECT query for the second table. The result of both query display in an array(). That both array() use for PHP array_intersect() Function like here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_intersect.asp

Answer (score -2):

I think he is not. He is looking

```
    SELECT * from A
    INTERSECT
    SELECT * FROM B
```

like that. But I don't know INTERSECT how is working.

Comment: MySQL does not support the intersect operator.

Comment: Yes, I know. I give an example.

Comment: Which is pointless, since it relies on a feature that is not supported by the rdbms the OP is working with.